# Thread synchronizing, using notifyAll()

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

This is an exercise from Bruce Eckel's Thinking in JAVA 3rd Edition, Revision 4.0, from chapter 13 (exercise 10). I am supposed to have a class that acts like a chef which gives out orders and notifies the waiters, and two waiters who wait for an order to be ready, and then take it.

Here's what i have so far:

```
class Order {
    private static int i = 0;
    private int count = i++;
    public Order() {
        if(count == 10) {
            System.out.println("Out of food, closing.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public String toString() {
            return "Order " + count;
    }
}
class WaitPerson extends Thread {
    public  Restaurant restaurant;
    private int waitPersonId;
    public WaitPerson(Restaurant r, int waitPersonId) {
        restaurant = r;
        this.waitPersonId = waitPersonId;
        start();
    }
    public void run() {
        Order currentOrder;
        while(true) {

            while(restaurant.order == null) {

                synchronized(Restaurant.waitpersonsList) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Waitperson" + this.waitPersonId + " is waiting...");
                        wait();
                        System.out.println("WaitPerson" + this.waitPersonId + " is attempting to get " + restaurant.order);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }

            currentOrder = restaurant.order;
            System.out.println("Waitperson" + this.waitPersonId + " got " + currentOrder);
            restaurant.order = null;

            try {
                sleep(3000); //waitperson is busy for 3 seconds
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Waitperson" + this.waitPersonId + " delivered " + currentOrder);

        }
    }
}
class Chef extends Thread {
    private Restaurant restaurant;
    private int ChefId;
    public Chef(Restaurant r, int ChefId) {
        restaurant = r;
        this.ChefId = ChefId;
        start();
    }
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            if(restaurant.order == null) {
                restaurant.order = new Order();
                System.out.println("Chef" + this.ChefId + ": Order up! ");
                synchronized(Restaurant.waitpersonsList) {
                    Restaurant.waitpersonsList.notifyAll();
                }
            }
            try {
                sleep(100);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Restaurant {
    public Order order;
    public static List<WaitPerson> waitpersonsList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<WaitPerson>());
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Restaurant r = new Restaurant();
        WaitPerson wp1 = new WaitPerson(r, 1);
        WaitPerson wp2 = new WaitPerson(r, 1);
        Restaurant.waitpersonsList.add(wp1);
        Restaurant.waitpersonsList.add(wp2);
        Chef chef = new Chef(r, 1);
    }
}
```

Everything is OK until the WaitPerson gets to the part where he is supposed to wait() 'till he gets notified. Then I get a an `IllegalMonitorStateException` which means the thread is waiting on an object's monitor without owning the specified monitor. Still, can't figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you've synchronized on the Restaurant.waitpersonsList, but then called wait on the WaitPerson. You must be synchronized on any object you call wait, notify or notifyAll on

```
             synchronized(Restaurant.waitpersonsList) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Waitperson" + this.waitPersonId + " is waiting...");
                    wait();
                    System.out.println("WaitPerson" + this.waitPersonId + " is attempting to get " + restaurant.order);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I was supposed to use Restaurant.waitpersonsList.wait();

Answer (score 2):

You are waiting on one object and notifying on another!

If you synchronize on the Restaurant.waitpersonsList then you need to wait on it too, whereas your wait() that throws the exception is trying to wait on the WaiterList object itself.